# Angular directive event binding not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

In short, my directive is successfully inserting the proper HTML but the bindings to events are not working.  Can anyone suggest why this is happening?

```
  . . .   directive('rcpRadio', [ function( ) {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            link: function (scope, element, attr, ctrl) {
                var label, elementHTML, selection, selectionName;

                    if (typeof(attr) != "undefined" && typeof(attr.label) != "undefined") {
                        label = attr.label;
                    } else {
                        label = "";
                    }
                    if (typeof(attr) != "undefined" && typeof(attr.selection) != "undefined") {
                        selection = attr.selection;
                    } else {
                        selection = "";
                    }
                    if (typeof(attr) != "undefined" && typeof(attr.selectionName) != "undefined") {
                        selectionName = attr.selectionName;
                    } else {
                        selectionName = "";
                    }
                    if (typeof(attr) != "undefined" && typeof(attr.isChecked) != "undefined" && attr.isChecked == "true") {
                        elementHTML = "<div class='switch radius nyes'><input type='radio' value='" + selection + "' name='" + selectionName + "' id='" + selectionName + "_id' checked ><label for='" + selectionName + "'></label><span> " + label + " </span></div>";
                    } else {
                        elementHTML = "<div class='switch radius nyes'><input type='radio' value='" + selection + "' name='" + selectionName + "' id='" + selectionName + "_id'  ><label for='" + selectionName + "'></label><span> " + label + " </span></div>";
                    }


                    element.replaceWith(elementHTML);

                    element.on('click', function(event) {
                    //element.bind('click', function (event) {
                        alert(":CLICK:");
                        console.log("## CLICK! :");
                        console.log(event);
                    });
                    element.bind('mouseover', function() {
                        console.log("## HOVER! :");
                        console.log(event);
                    });
            }
    };
}]);
```

I really just want to call a function when any change to the inserted HTML is detected.

Any ideas would be much appreciated.  I am pulling my hair out!

#### Update 7/28/2014 4:06

Well, by shifting away from "replaceWith" and instead using :

```
template: "<div class='switch radius'><input type='radio' value='{{selection}}' name='{{selectionName}}' id='{{selectionName}}_id' checked=''><label for='currentMode'></label><span> {{label}} </span></div>",
```

With some additions made to scope updates in link like:

```
$scope.label = attr.label;
```

Seems to then allow the event binding. So does replaceWith prevent event binding? I am so confused . .

Comment: Do you think ng-pristine or ng-dirty would help you out? https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you could do the DOM transform in 'compile' function. Try to implement like this:

```
directive('rcpRadio', [ function( ) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        compile: function(element,attr){
            //transform DOM according to attribute
            var label, elementHTML, selection, selectionName;

            if (typeof(attr) != "undefined" && typeof(attr.label) != "undefined") {
                label = attr.label;
            } else {
                label = "";
            }
            if (typeof(attr) != "undefined" && typeof(attr.selection) != "undefined") {
                selection = attr.selection;
            } else {
                selection = "";
            }
            if (typeof(attr) != "undefined" && typeof(attr.selectionName) != "undefined") {
                selectionName = attr.selectionName;
            } else {
                selectionName = "";
            }
            if (typeof(attr) != "undefined" && typeof(attr.isChecked) != "undefined" && attr.isChecked == "true") {
                elementHTML = "<div class='switch radius nyes'><input type='radio' value='" + selection + "' name='" + selectionName + "' id='" + selectionName + "_id' checked ><label for='" + selectionName + "'></label><span> " + label + " </span></div>";
            } else {
                elementHTML = "<div class='switch radius nyes'><input type='radio' value='" + selection + "' name='" + selectionName + "' id='" + selectionName + "_id'  ><label for='" + selectionName + "'></label><span> " + label + " </span></div>";
            }

            element.replaceWith(elementHTML);

            //return link function

            return function(scope,element,attr){
                element.on('click', function(event) {
                //element.bind('click', function (event) {
                    alert(":CLICK:");
                    console.log("## CLICK! :");
                    console.log(event);
                });
                element.bind('mouseover', function() {
                    console.log("## HOVER! :");
                    console.log(event);
                });
            };
        }
    }
}]);
```

#### Here is a [jsFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tDrMz/1/)